# Jquery Disable Next button until animation finishes

Tags: jquery, jquery-cycle

This is cool and I am familiar with this. However I want the next and previous buttons to stay visible, just not be click able. In my particular situation, the buttons are images that are part of the design. I just want the user to not be able to click through before an animation ends.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$(function(){
    $("#previous").bind("click", Previous);
    $("#next").bind("click", Next);
});

function DoAnimation() {
    $("#previous,#next").unbind("click");
    $('#id').animate(
        complete: function() {
            $(this).after('<div>Animation complete.</div>');
            $("#previous").bind("click", Previous);
            $("#next").bind("click", Next);
        }
    });
}

function Previous() { }
function Next() { }
```

Answer (score 8):

one more technique:

```
$(".next,.prev").click(function(){
    if ($('#my_animated_elelement').is(':animated'))
    {
        return false;
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have javascript calls for the images onclick's, use a variable `MyApp.IgnoreNextPrevClicks` to flag whether the onclick handlers do execute or not.

```
MyApp={}
MyApp.IgnoreNextPrevClicks=false;
MyApp.PrevClick=function() {
    if(MyApp.IgnoreNextPrevClicks) return;
    //real work goes here
}
```

now before calling the jquery animator, set `MyApp.IgnoreNextPrevClicks` to true, and set it back to false after the animation ends (use jquery animation callback).

Answer (score 0):

```
function btn() {
   $('#btn').one('click', function(){
     //call your animation function here.

     setTimeout(btn, animation duration);
  });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$('#mybtn').attr("disabled","disabled"); // to Disable Button

$('#mybtn').removeAttr("disabled"); // to Enable Disabled button
```